# Why does the Vue3 router not match a route?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 router set up like this:

```js
var router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHistory('/v3/app/'),
  routes: [
    { path: '/index', component: Vue.defineAsyncComponent(() => import('/components/index.js')), name: "index" },
    { path: '/three', component: Vue.defineAsyncComponent(() => import('/components/three.js')), name: "three" },
  ],
});
```

However, when I navigate to http://localhost:3000/v3/app/#/three nothing happens and I get a message in the console that says:

```
[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/#/three"
```

A dump of routes via `console.log(JSON.stringify(router.getRoutes()))` shows this:

```js
[
  {
    "path": "/index",
    "name": "index",
    "meta": {},
    "props": {
      "default": false
    },
    "children": [],
    "instances": {},
    "leaveGuards": {},
    "updateGuards": {},
    "enterCallbacks": {},
    "components": {
      "default": {
        "name": "AsyncComponentWrapper"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "path": "/three",
    "name": "three",
    "meta": {},
    "props": {
      "default": false
    },
    "children": [],
    "instances": {},
    "leaveGuards": {},
    "updateGuards": {},
    "enterCallbacks": {},
    "components": {
      "default": {
        "name": "AsyncComponentWrapper"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and adding a default route ("/") results in everything going to the default route.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: `/three` is different from `/#/three`.

Comment: @kissu do you mean that vue.js don't use hash-based routing anymore? and adding ```/#/three``` to the routes does not result in different behaviour

Comment: Here, you're using `createWebHistory` hence the [html5 mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode) indeed. I didn't saw hash routes for a long time in production apps tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is not matching because you're trying to match `/three` (HTML5 history mode) with `/#/three` (hash history mode).

Using `createWebHistory` and rewriting everything into non-hash routes as [shown here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode) may be a good solution. Especially because this is the default/most common approach nowadays!